# Cylindrical capacitor and charge density per unit area

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, voltage, capacitance, gauss-law

I am dealing with the following problem:

Assume that a charge has been placed on the inner cylinder, and that the entire charge is distributed on the outer surface of the inner cylinder as shown in the figure, giving a surface charge $$σ_1=8.0 \mu C/m^2$$How large will the surface charge be on the inner surface of the outer cylinder?
The radius $R_1$ of the outer surface of the inner cylinder is 5.0 cm, and the radius $R_2$ of the inner surface of the outer cylinder is 7.0 cm. We assume that the cylinders are long, and that we are examining an area far from the ends of the cylinders. There is air between the cylinders.

[image]

I am advised to use Gauss surface, so this is how I worked:
The law entails that
$$\oint_S \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A} = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$We can draw our gaussian surface between the two cylinders passing through a point of interest P.

We can divide the integral of the surface into the sum of three areas, the top, the middle (a rectangle), and the bottom.

The integral of the top and bottom are zero, because the electric field is perpendicular to the $dA$. The integral of the side piece (the rectangle) is the $2h\pi r_{p}$ where $h$ is the height of the cylinder and $r_p$ is the radius of the cylinder (the gaussian surface).

The electric field is constant, so I eventually have:$${E}\cdot 2h\pi r_{p} = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$

Calculating the potential using the previous expression, we have: $$V=\frac{Q_{enc}}{2\pi \epsilon_0 h} \ln{\frac{R_2}{R_1}}$$

Since $C=Q/V$ we get $$C=2\pi \epsilon_0 h \frac{1}{\ln{\frac{R_2}{R_1}}}$$

Where I am getting confused is: Should calculate the capacitance by substituting the enclosed charge by $σ_1 2h \pi R_1$ then calculate the charge density $σ_2$ using the arrived to value of the capacitance?

Answer (score 1):

"How large will the surface charge be on the inner surface of the outer cylinder?"

If this is all you want, I recommend that you consider a cylindrical Gaussian surface of axial length $l$, coaxial with the metal cylinders – I'm assuming they're metal  – and of radius, $r$, a little greater than 7.0 cm, so that its curved surface is wholly inside the metal itself of the outer cylinder. Ask yourself what the electric field strength is (in electrostatic conditions) at all points on this curved surface and convince yourself that there is no flux of electric field through the end-discs of the cylinder. Now apply Gauss's law to find the total enclosed charge. It is then only a short step to $\sigma_2$, since you know $\sigma_1,\ R_1,\ R_2$ !

*Added after decent interval*: Since $\vec E=0$ everywhere in the metal (otherwise there'd be a drift of free electrons), there is no flux of electric field through the curved part of the gaussian surface. Since, between the metal cylinders, $\vec E$ is, by symmetry, radial there is no electric flux through the end discs of the surface, either. So Gauss's law tells us that there is no net charge inside the gaussian surface. So we have
$$2\pi R_1l\sigma_1 + 2\pi R_2l\sigma_2=0$$
$$\text{So}\ \ \ \ \sigma_2=-\sigma_1\frac{R_1}{R_2}$$